# play .ts file on chrome with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-chrome, mpeg2-ts

I am trying to play a .ts file on chrome, but getting the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

Here's my function and this works for me when the extension is `mp4`. How can i get fix this to play .ts extensions?

```
  var vid;
  function play_video(video, width, height) {
    if (vid == null) {
      vid = document.createElement("video");
      document.body.appendChild(vid);
    }
    vid.source = { src: video, type: "video/ts" };
    vid.width = width;
    vid.height = height;
    vid.loop = true;
    vid.muted = true;
    vid.src = video;
    vid.type = "video/ts";
    vid.play();
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that chrome supports this format? https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/

Comment: Unless TS is synonymous with one of the formats listed [here](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/), you don't. Convert it to one of the formats, and use that instead.